# if and else statement time and a half

Tags: python

So i'm suppose to write  code on how to calculate an employees pay any employee that worked past 40 are paid in times and half so hears my code

```
hours = int(input('how many hours did you work'))
hour = int(input('how many hours did you work overtime'))
rate = 1.50
pay = hours*rate

if hours>40:
    pay = 40*1.5+hour*(1.5*rate)
else:
    40<hours

print('you earned',pay)
```

my brother said its suppose to ask you once not twice so help maybe

Comment: `else: 40<hours`, huh? Probably, better chose a language with curly braces :)

Comment: I edited as what python will interpret so it's kinda clear that there is an error here. Use indent correctly or reformat exactly as you wrote in your code... if you intended "else if" it's written `elif 40<hours:`

Comment: You need to do more Python tutorials. It seems to me you are writing code more or less randomly and hoping it will work. Programming doesn't work that way,

Answer (score 1):

If you know that overtime is anything past 40 hours, you can compare the number of hours the person worked to 40 to figure out the amount of overtime instead of asking the user for the amount of overtime separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate overtime by realizing that it is `hours - 40` or zero, whichever is greater.  Also, regular hours is capped at 40 hours.  So `min` and `max` would be helpful here:

```
hours = int(input('how many hours did you work'))
wageRate = 1.50
overtimeRate = wageRate * 1.5
pay = min(40, hours) * wageRate           # regular hours
pay += max(hours - 40, 0) * overtimeRate  # add overtime
print('you earned',pay)
```

Comment: What is wrong with this answer, so that I can fix it?

Comment: it's rate = 1.5 that's the problem  Your calculation should be (rate * min(40, hrs)) + (max (0, hrs - 40) * 1.5 * rate).  @Nirks answer below is using 'rate' to mean the overtime charge, which is always 1.5.  Maybe calling it OT instead of 'rate' would clear that up

Comment: I just have that on two separate lines (one for regular pay, and one for overtime)

Comment: only in the case where the hourly pay is $1.50 :)

Comment: I'm confused now, isn't overtime rate `rate * 1.5`?

Comment: In @nirks example yes. In yours it's the standin for wages (you hardcoded the overtime charge in line 4 so storing it in a variable is not needed).

Comment: hourly_wages = 16.00
pay = min(40, hours) * hourly_wages
pay += max(0, hours-40) * hourly_wage * 1.5 

Dang I wish you could put code in comments :)

Comment: I think OP wanted the `rate` variable to be the pay/hour or wages rate.  I'll edit answer to clarify

Answer (score 1):

```
hours = int(input('how many hours did you work? '))
rate = 1.5 # or whatever normal pay rate is
pay = rate * (hours + 0.5 * max(hours-40,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify @jh314's question.

```
hours = float (input('how many hours did you work?'))  # < hours can be fractional
OT = 1.5        # OT calculation in US.  A constant for this purpose
WAGES = 16.00   #  hourly rate, also usually a float!
pay = min(hours, 40) * WAGES 
pay += max(hours - 40, 0) * WAGES * OT
print "You earned  $ %0.2f " % pay
```

For a real application you'd probably calculate it using the employee's specific rate:

```
def calc_wages( hrs, rate):
    OT = 1.5
    pay = min(hours, 40) * rate
    pay += max(hours - 40, 0) * rate * OT
    return pay
```

Comment: seems like @jh and I had dueling edits... the answers are now effectively the same except I added float handling and 2 decimal place printout